# Websockets fail in production on my node server hosted on EC2 using nginx. Any tips on how to debug a 1006 abnormal closure error from postman?

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, websocket

I have been struggling with getting my websockets to work for a livestreaming application I am building. The app is built using the PERN stack and I am using [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws). The websockets work perfectly on localhost. The problem is when I try to connect to my websockets in production on my [site](https://www.ohmystream.co/broadcast). If I try using postman to test the websockets production url I get the error below which says '1006 Abnormal Closure: No close frame was received'. I am hosting my server code on EC2 with nginx. The REST API endpoints work perfectly in production, it is just the websocket in production that is not working. My inbound and outbound rules for EC2 allow for all traffic at the moment. Any hints on what I should be checking to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name ohmystream.xyz www.ohmystream.xyz;

    location /websocket {
            # redirect all ws traffic to localhost:8080
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ohmystream.xyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ohmystream.xyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}

server {
    if ($host = www.ohmystream.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = ohmystream.xyz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name ohmystream.xyz www.ohmystream.xyz;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Here is my client code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar/Navbar'
import BroadcastButton from '../../components/Buttons/BroadcastButton'
import Timer from '../../components/Timer/Timer'
import formatTime from '../../utils/formatTime'
import getCookie from '../../utils/getCookie'
import API from '../../api/api'
import './Broadcast.css'

const CAPTURE_OPTIONS = {
  audio: true,
  video: true,
}

function Broadcast() {
  const [isVideoOn, setisVideoOn] = useState(true)
  const [mute, setMute] = useState(false)
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0)
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)

  const [twitchStreamKey, setTwitchStreamKey] = useState('')
  const [youtubeStreamKey, setYoutubeStreamKey] = useState('')
  const [facebookStreamKey, setFacebookStreamKey] = useState('')

  const [mediaStream, setMediaStream] = useState(null)
  const [userFacing, setuserFacing] = useState(false)

  const videoRef = useRef()
  const ws = useRef()

  let liveStream
  let liveStreamRecorder

  if (mediaStream && videoRef.current && !videoRef.current.srcObject) {
    videoRef.current.srcObject = mediaStream
  }

  async function enableStream() {
    try {
      let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: isVideoOn,
        audio: true,
      })
      setMediaStream(stream)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mediaStream) {
      enableStream()
    } else {
      return function cleanup() {
        mediaStream.getVideoTracks().forEach((track) => {
          track.stop()
        })
      }
    }
  }, [mediaStream])

  useEffect(() => {
    let userId = getCookie('userId')

    API.post('/destinations', { userId })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response) {
          setTwitchStreamKey(response.data.twitch_stream_key)
          setYoutubeStreamKey(response.data.youtube_stream_key)
          setFacebookStreamKey(response.data.facebook_stream_key)
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    ws.current =
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? new WebSocket(
            'wss://www.ohmystream.xyz/websocket' +
              `?twitchStreamKey=${twitchStreamKey}&youtubeStreamKey=${youtubeStreamKey}&facebookStreamKey=${facebookStreamKey}`
          )
        : new WebSocket(
            `ws://localhost:8080` +
              `?twitchStreamKey=${twitchStreamKey}&youtubeStreamKey=${youtubeStreamKey}&facebookStreamKey=${facebookStreamKey}`
          )

    console.log(ws.current)

    ws.current.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket Open')
    }

    ws.current.onerror = function (event) {
      console.error('WebSocket error observed:', event)
      console.log(event)
    }

    return () => {
      ws.current.close()
    }
  }, [twitchStreamKey, youtubeStreamKey])

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null
    if (isActive) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setSeconds((seconds) => seconds + 1)
      }, 1000)
    } else if (!isActive && seconds !== 0) {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [isActive, seconds])

  const toggle = () => {
    setIsActive(!isActive)
  }

  const startStream = () => {
    if (!twitchStreamKey || !youtubeStreamKey) {
      alert(
        'Please add your twitch and youtube stream keys first under destinations'
      )
    } else {
      toggle()
      liveStream = videoRef.current.captureStream(30) // 30 FPS
      liveStreamRecorder = new MediaRecorder(liveStream, {
        mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=h264',
        videoBitsPerSecond: 3 * 1024 * 1024,
      })
      liveStreamRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
        ws.current.send(e.data)
        console.log('send data', e.data)
      }
      // Start recording, and dump data every second
      liveStreamRecorder.start(1000)
    }
  }

  const stopStream = () => {
    setIsActive(false)
    ws.current.close()
    liveStreamRecorder = null
    // liveStreamRecorder.stop()
  }

  const toggleMute = () => {
    setMute(!mute)
  }

  const toggleCamera = () => {
    // toggle camera on and off here
    setisVideoOn(false)
  }

  const recordScreen = async () => {
    let stream
    !userFacing
      ? (stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(CAPTURE_OPTIONS))
      : (stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(CAPTURE_OPTIONS))
    setMediaStream(stream)
    videoRef.current.srcObject = stream
    setuserFacing(!userFacing)
  }

  const handleCanPlay = () => {
    videoRef.current.play()
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className='dashboard-container'>
        <div id='container'>
          <div
            style={
              seconds === 0
                ? { visibility: 'hidden' }
                : { visibility: 'visible' }
            }
          >
            <Timer>
              {isActive ? 'LIVE' : 'END'}: {formatTime(seconds)}
            </Timer>
          </div>
          <video
            className='video-container'
            ref={videoRef}
            onCanPlay={handleCanPlay}
            autoPlay
            playsInline
            muted={mute}
          />
        </div>
        <div className='button-container'>
          <BroadcastButton
            title={!isActive ? 'Go Live' : 'Stop Recording'}
            fx={!isActive ? startStream : stopStream}
          />
          {/* <BroadcastButton title='Disable Camera' fx={toggleCamera} /> */}
          <BroadcastButton
            title={!userFacing ? 'Share Screen' : 'Stop Sharing'}
            fx={recordScreen}
          />
          <BroadcastButton title={!mute ? 'Mute' : 'Muted'} fx={toggleMute} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Broadcast
```

[image: Postman testing production ws]
[image: error displayed in the console in chrome]
[image: EC2 inbound rules]
[image: EC2 outbound rules]

Comment: How does your backend websocket setup look like?

Comment: @Fide Here is the server code: https://github.com/toshvelaga/livestream/blob/main/server/server.js

Comment: I did get postman to start working by downloading ffmpeg in my ec2 instance: https://ibb.co/7gzSs0D, but it still doesn't work in production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did end up getting it to work after a lot of trial and error. The only thing I really changed was my nginx configuration and the port that my websockets were on. I changed the port from 8080 to 3001 for the websockets.

Also here is my updated nginx with the changes I made.

```
        location /websocket {
            proxy_pass http://ohmystream.xyz:3001;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
        }
```